# What if the "catch" block is empty - "{}"

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is it proper to use below syntax for try catch??

```
try
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c=a+b;
}
catch (exception ex)
{
//Nothing here    
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes and No.

Leaving the catch block *completely* empty ...

```
catch( Exception ) 
{
}
```

... should be a hanging offence.

Having an empty catch block that contains a meaningful, detailed **comment** about why it's OK to ignore this particular exception (and any sub-classes thereof) *might* be acceptable, but only in very limited circumstances.

Re-throwing the *same* exception should only be done when you have a list of catch blocks and you need to "smuggle" a smaller Exception past the attention of a "larger" Exception handler (say, throwing a FileNotFound Exception to the "Outside World" but doing something different with any other IOException).

The most important part of Exception Handling is the "Handling" part and, if you're not doing anything *useful* when catching an Exception, then you shouldn't be catching it *at all*.  (Is "smothering" an exception useful?  YMMV).

Comment: Agree Phill...
Sometimes it is not mandatory to throw an exception and go outside but atleast it cannot affect our execution flow.

Comment: @Wilman: Whilst I agree that never is a strong word, NEVER catch (Exception) and swallow it. That will catch OutOfMemoryException, for example, which really should be thrown up to a handler at the top level. If you want to catch a *specific* kind of exception and swallow it then a comment is enough -- but that should be a rare case.

Comment: Rethrowing the same exception is done often in the case in which you simply need to know if an operation failed and must do something in that case, like say transaction rollback.

Comment: @Neil, but if you're rolling back a transaction (doing something useful), then the catch block *isn't* empty, which is what we're focussing on here.

Answer (score 5):

**No, no and no**

It is never appropriate to ignore exceptions like this. As a bare minimum, you should log the exception so that you can figure out what went wrong at a later point. Exception handling isn't sports fishing, you don't catch exceptions for the fun of it. You catch them because you intend to do something with them.

Comment: if we add 
throw ex;

Then what will happen??

Comment: That adds nothing valueable and just clutters up the code...

Comment: Rethrowing exceptions can be useful in order to do something on an exception, so it would be like not catching it at all, except that you can do something when it does, like a transaction rollback.

Comment: If do *do* something yes, But I think he's referring to the empty catch in de original question with just the added throw ex; which adds nothing...

Comment: @Wilman If you rethrow using `throw ex;` instead of `throw;` you overwrite the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Very  very rarely. The only exception i use on a
regular basis is creating a directory that might or might not exist and then I only catch the specific exception that might be thrown in case the directory exists.

Answer (score 0):

This would simply eat up any exception being raised. Without any notification or logging.

If that exception appears at runtime, It would be really difficult to detect that It occurred and resolve the issue.

So we never eat up the exception until it is really intended. Even if it is intended, we log that in the log files.